# Are there any alternative programmable networks to Ethereum?

Tags: network

Are there any alternative networks to Ethereum which are also being developed (which can compete) and can work in similar way in terms of storing and executing decentralized programmable code blocks? Which may for example deal with certain limitations in different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rootstock would be the main example, check out their site for more info 
http://www.rootstock.io/

They use bitcoin instead of using their own coin, but they are not as far along with the smart contracts as Ethereum is, they just recently got their test net up.

Answer (score 2):

"Decentralized" does not necessarily mean "public", therefore you might be interested in [Eris](https://erisindustries.com/) or [Tendermint](http://tendermint.com/) (which is used by Eris under the hood).

Answer (score 2):

[Lisk](https://lisk.io/) is another example of an Ethereum alternative. They use Javascript as their smart contract programming language. Every Lisk app exists as its own sidechain.

Given their choice of Javascript, it's possible to introduce non-deterministic behavior in Lisk apps (via `Math.random()`) that can cause Lisk sidechains to fork. The [Lisk documentation](https://lisk.io/documentation?i=lisk-dapps-docs/README) suggests that you should not do this, but if you do, the damage will be contained to the sidechain and not effect Lisk itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget about forks of the Ethereum main network itself, which the question does not explicitly exclude. The main one is [Ethereum Classic](https://ethereumclassic.github.io/), there is also [Expanse](http://www.expanse.tech/).

Answer (score 1):

1. [Stratis](https://stratisplatform.com/) for .net framework development(c#),
2. [Neo](https://neo.org/)(is called `Chinese Ethereum`) supports [multi programming language](http://docs.neo.org/en-us/sc/introduction.html)( C#, VB.Net, F# ,Java, Kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

[Quorum](https://www.jpmorgan.com/country/US/EN/Quorum) is a Ethereum compatible private network modified to provide 3rd party observer abilities but still have private transactions.

> Quorum™ is an enterprise-focused version of Ethereum.
>
> Quorum is ideal for any application requiring high speed and high
>   throughput processing of private transactions within a permissioned
>   group of known participants. Quorum addresses specific challenges to
>   blockchain technology adoption within the financial industry, and
>   beyond.

Comment: 'permissioned' - therein lies the problem....